# Reset event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm building validation for form fields for a form. So, I need to do a validation which I do like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submitbutton').click(function() {

        if (validateField()) {
            $('form.checkout_form_validate').submit(function(event) {
                return true;
            });
        }
        else {
             $('form.checkout_form_validate').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
       }
    });


    function validateField() {
        var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
        var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
        var shipping_address = $('#shipping_address_1').val();
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var state = $('#state').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();

        if (first_name == "" || last_name == "" || shipping_address == "" || city == "" || state == "" || phone == "") {
            $('#errorcontainer').html('Fill out all the required fields <br/>');
            $('#errorcontainer').fadeIn('fast');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

});
```

So, If a user just press the submit button, it will throw an error and Form will not submit, But, If after doing this, the user fills out the entire form and then hit submit, Nothing will happen even when `validateField()` is true.
How to "reset" it? Any ideas ?

Comment: On each click on submit button, you are binding new form submit handler. Don't nest events...

Comment: In this cases i am using ajax to send the validated data to the server.

Comment: @user3850805 Which is not a very good idea...

Comment: why is that bad idea?

Comment: @user3850805 Like said, you are binding on each click new submit handler so any previous bound ones still fired and so on...

Comment: Alrighty. I'm a newbie.. so, sloppy code. I'm sorry. Mods please remove this question!

Answer (score 3):

> On each click on submit button, you are binding new form submit
>   handler. Don't nest events...

You validation logic should be:

```
$(function() {
  $('form.checkout_form_validate').submit(function(event) {
    return validateField();
  });
});

function validateField() {
  var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
  var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
  var shipping_address = $('#shipping_address_1').val();
  var city = $('#city').val();
  var state = $('#state').val();
  var phone = $('#phone').val();

  if (first_name == "" || last_name == "" || shipping_address == "" || city == "" || state == "" || phone == "") {
    $('#errorcontainer').html('Fill out all the required fields <br/>');
    $('#errorcontainer').fadeIn('fast');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need e.preventDefault(); and a return false; statement,  they do the same thing

return false within a jQuery event handler = e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation()